# locale LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8" but sorting by german words doesn't work in postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I created a table with the settings as

```
CREATE DATABASE myDB ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'de_DE.utf8' LC_CTYPE = 'de_DE.utf8' OWNER = owner --locale=de_DE;"
```

As I run `SHOW lc_collate I get :de_DE.utf8`
the operating system is ubuntu

I am working in docker, but my c library is: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31`

but by sorting, all german special characters go to the end for example Ä goes after z.but I expect sorting like a,ä,b,.....z.

I tried to use another image with the command :

```
RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8
```

and it worked

but as I run the same command with my current image which can not be changed, I get error

every help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you need to use an ICU collation to get the sorting right. But you can't specify that during database creation, only per column.

Comment: I cannot believe that. Please run `SHOW lc_collate;` and show the exact statement you ran. Also, what is your operating system and C library? Please add the information to the question; don't write a comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. tnx, but can you please shortly tell me how can I use that

Comment: You didn't add all the information I asked you for...

Comment: I don't know about C library. sorry. actually I am working in docker, and I created my DB in the docker

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name TNX. it looks fine, but as I run ...... ORDER BY name  collate "de-DE.UTF8"; I get the error :  collation "de-DE.UTF8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist. I tried different collates: as "de_DE.utf8" but the same error

Comment: `collate "de_DE.utf8"` works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c8e78f153019b5d7b35e636cc7ada870 - however _that_ name depends on the operating system you are using (`de_DE.utf8` is only available on Linux, on Windows the name would be different). The ICU collation `"de-DE-x-icu"` is independent of the operating system

Comment: my os has the locale as: de_DE.utf8, but maybe it is because I am working on docker and I should set those locale in my docker as well?

Comment: The operating system used by the docker image is relevant, not the host OS.

Comment: tanx a lot, I think you brought me to the right direction, now I should create the locale in my docker, where my DB is running. right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. tanx again for your support. finally I was able to get locale on my container. BUT I don't have de_DE.utf8 on my locale, 
the locale in my container is : de_DE. and as my collate in db is de_DE.utf8
when I write : ..... ORDER BY name collate "de_DE.utf8"
I get this error: ERROR: collation "de_DE.utf8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
and as I write the query as : ...ORDER BY name collate "de_DE". I get no error by sorting is not correct. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use `order by ... collate "de-DE-x-icu"` that collation should always be present.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. sorry for interrupting and thanks for your help. but this one doesn't work either. I tried with another image, it worked as I added this line:

RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8

but as with my image tried to run that command I got this error:

The command '/bin/sh -c localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8' returned a non-zero code: 127, Code: 127

Can you please help me how make the localdef to be run?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PostgreSQL has some different `DE` collations. For viewing all Postgres Collations list you can execute this SQL script:

```
SELECT c.oid, c.collname, c.collcollate, c.collctype  FROM pg_catalog.pg_collation c 
ORDER BY c.collname
```

For testing I execute this script in my server and i gets this collates:

```
de-AT-x-icu     de-AT   de-AT
de-BE-x-icu     de-BE   de-BE
de-CH-x-icu     de-CH   de-CH
de-DE-x-icu     de-DE   de-DE
de-IT-x-icu     de-IT   de-IT
de-LI-x-icu     de-LI   de-LI
de-LU-x-icu     de-LU   de-LU
de-x-icu        de      de
```

Somebodies don't know that you can create a database with customs you needed collating. In PostgreSQL when you are using standard `CREATE DATABASE` command you can not set any custom type of collates to Database, database collate gets automatically during creating process from the Regional Parameters of Operation System. But, when you create a database from `template0` then you can select any custom collating. For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db
WITH OWNER "postgres"
ENCODING 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'de-DE'
LC_CTYPE = 'de-DE'
TEMPLATE template0;
```